# Strange highlighting on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have my own subclass of a `UITableViewCell` which I would like to customise when the user presses down on the cell.

So, I tried overriding the following method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (highlighted)
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        [self.optionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.optionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    }

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
}
```

This works fine if I press and hold down on the cell. But if I quickly tap the cell, my `UITableView` catches the delegate callback `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and you can't see any of my above code take effect.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can handle the case when the cell is selected rather than highlighted. Something like :

```
    - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
        [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
        [self updateCell];
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
        [self updateCell];
    }

    - (void)updateCell {
        if (self.highlighted || self.selected) {
            [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
            [self.optionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        } else {
            [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [self.optionLabel setTextColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        }
    }
```